# Save git log in file (with tags because they are missing)

Tags: git, shell, sh

I have a simple question. 
I am trying to save my git log in a file. 
If i use the command:

```
git log --oneline --tags
```

I can see my complete git log like this:

```
67**** (HEAD -> supertag2, tag: ***, origin/***) version t1.1
47**** [Story] Some Exampe Text Blub blubb
a7**** (tag: superTag2) New Version 1.1
13**** Some Exampe Text Blub blubb
46**** (tag: superTag1) New Version 1.0
```

After that, when I use this command:

```
git log --oneline --tags 2>&1 > /Users/user/Stuff/log.txt
```

it is only saving the data without the tags (In brackets).

Like this:

```
67**** version t1.1
47**** [Story] Some Exampe Text Blub blubb
a7**** New Version 1.1
13**** Some Exampe Text Blub blubb
46**** New Version 1.0
```

what am I doing wrong? I thought that GIT is using stdout? Or what is wrong? :-(

Greetings

Comment: Add `--decorate`.

Comment: Thank you. with decorate, it is working. :-)